FutureWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a DataFrame or Series through chained assignment in Pandas
I'm encountering a FutureWarning when trying to fill missing values in the "age" column of my DataFrame with the mean of the column. The warning suggests that the behavior will change in Pandas 3.0, and the inplace method will not work as expected due to the intermediate object always behaving as a copy.
Here is the warning message I receive
FutureWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a DataFrame or Series through chained assignment using an inplace method.

The behavior will change in pandas 3.0. This inplace method will never work because the intermediate object on which we are setting values always behaves as a copy.
I understand that this issue arises from using the inplace parameter with chained assignment. Here’s the code that triggers the warning
df['age'].fillna(df['age'].mean(), inplace=True)

I need an alternative approach that updates the DataFrame without using inplace=True and avoids the warning. I tried the following methods, but they didn’t change the DataFrame as expected

Reassigning the result back to the column

df['age'] = df['age'].fillna(df['age'].mean())


Using a dictionary with fillna

df.fillna({'age': df['age'].mean()}, inplace=True)

Despite these attempts, the DataFrame still shows 891 missing values in the "age" column after trying to fill them.

I can't reproduce your issue, the two workarounds work fine, as expected. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrate the issue. For example [edit] your question and add the output of df['age'].tolist()

I had the exact same issue and the two work arounds you have described fixed the issue for me. There may be some other underlying small issue involved such as a misspelling in a variable.

Let's try the following code:
import pandas as pd

l=[2,4,'nan',5,'nan']
df=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['age'])
df=df.astype(float)  #Add this row
# df['age'].fillna(df['age'].mean(), inplace=True)  #delete this row
df['age']=df['age'].fillna(df['age'].mean()) #use this row instead of the previous row


I get the same warning with the code below and fillna doesn't actually fills the NaN values.
dfs = [train, test]

m_age = train['Age'].median()
m_fare = train['Fare'].median()

for df in dfs:
  df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(m_age, inplace=True)
  df['Fare'] = df['Fare'].fillna(m_fare, inplace=True)
   

But then I do
m_age = train['Age'].median()
m_fare = train['Fare'].median()

train['Age'] = train['Age'].fillna(m_age)
test['Age'] = test['Age'].fillna(m_age)

train['Fare'] = train['Fare'].fillna(m_fare)
test['Fare'] = test['Fare'].fillna(m_fare)

without inplace=True and everything works fine, NaNs are gone. Magic to me, still don't know why this happens
